# Correctly changing Tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to change a label in my Tkinter GUI with the following code:

```
import os
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
import threading
import queue
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from time import time
import minimalmodbus
import serial
minimalmodbus.CLOSE_PORT_AFTER_EACH_CALL = True
THREAD_LOCK = threading.Lock()

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

       self.temp_label = tk.Label(self, text='temp', width=10)
       self.temp_label.pack(side="top")

       self.connect_button = tk.Button(self, text='Connect', command=self.run_code)
       self.connect_button.pack(side="top")

    def run_code(self):
        all_thread()

    def set_result(self, read):
        self.temp_label.config(text=read[2])

def all_thread(): #not in class Page1()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=all_process)
    thread.start()

def all_process():
    gas = minimalmodbus.Instrument("COM3", 1)
    gas.serial.baudrate = 9600
    gas.serial.bytesize = 8
    gas.serial.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
    gas.serial.stopbits = 1
    gas.serial.timeout = 0.25
    gas.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU

    gas_list = [gas]
    processes = []
    while len(gas_list) > 0:
        val = 1
        with THREAD_LOCK:
            for sen in gas_list:
                proc = Process(target=main_reader, args=(sen, val))
                processes.append(proc)
                proc.start()
                val += 1
            for sen in processes:
                sen.join()
            time.sleep(1)

def main_reader(sen, val):
    try:
        read = sen.read_registers(0,42)
    except OSError:
        read = "Communication Error"
    except ValueError:
        read = "RTU Error"
    if val == 1:
        Page1().set_result(read)


class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 1", command=p1.lift)
        b1.pack(side="left")
        p1.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("1000x600")
    root.mainloop()
```

I want to change the text of `temp_label` to the 3rd item in the `read` list. However, the `set_result` function is not working properly. When the data gets to `set_result` the text in the `temp_label` is not changed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your example there's no call to `set_result` function, hence no one knows what `read` is.

Comment: I forgot to add the function that deals with that...my bad. Question was edited to include that function, `main_reader`.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Have you verified that `read` is what you think it is?

Comment: Yes, `read` gets to `set_result` and is the list I want. The label won't change still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least part of the problem is that you are creating a *new* `Page1` that is invisible. So even if you do change the value, you won't see it.

You need to be calling `p1.set_result`, by either making `p1` global, making `p1` an instance variable of `main`, or passing it to the function that needs it.

Even with that, this isn't going to work. You can't call tkinter methods from a process or thread other than the one that created the widgets. You'll have to put data on a queue in the other threads/processes, and poll the queue in the GUI thread.

Comment: Firstly, I think you've answered all my Tkinter questions and I want to thank you for your help and patience! Secondly, if I went a different way with the code, like having all the processes, threads, and functions under one application class, would this work?